# how to pass data as an arguments between two java classes using node js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

i have two java classes ,
and i want to take the output of the first java class ,pass this data to Node Js then, finally this data must move from Node Js to the other Java class as arguments

this the first java class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx) {
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println("Generated : \t" + randomInt + "\t time:\t" + timestamp);
            //System.out.println("Generated : \t" + randomInt + "\t time:\t" + timeStamp);

        }

    }
```

then this is the second one

```
String msg = args[]

producer.send(new KeyedMessage("topic",msg));
```

**i need to do this job using Node Js**

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many approaches available. Some of them are:

- Insert data into a database from JAVA, retrieve that data from Node.JS, modify it, update the database, and finally retrieve it from JAVA.
- Send an HTTP request from JAVA to Node.JS, modify it, then send a request back to JAVA and be ready to listen for it.
- Establish a socket connection between JAVA and Node.JS so they communicate between each other in real time.

Comment: thanks , can i do this using in the place of java class ,jar file, and excuse because i am newbie with node js if there any example will be more helpful